# vb.net . how to add row using key enter ,additional cell focused cell

Tags: vb.net

can you help me 
because i stuck in this code when i press enter in cell(0) this event goto to  another form to get data and the data I input into the datagridview which is in the first form where there is a sum between the cell, where the value of cell (6) is the sum of the second cell and the third cell, then I want to focuskan to the cell to the cell (2 ), If cell (5) it's value is 0 it will focus to that cell when i hit enter in cell (2)

```
 Private Sub tb_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tb.KeyDown
    If tb.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Enter
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
                Dim frm As New f_pilihbarangreturbeli
                Dim hitung As Double
                With frm
                    .ShowDialog()
                    .tampil()
                    Dim duplikasi As Boolean = False
                    If Not .a = "" Then
                        For Each i As DataGridViewRow In tb.Rows
                            If Not i.IsNewRow Then
                                If i.Cells(0).Value.ToString = .a Then
                                    duplikasi = True
                                    i.Cells(3).Value += 1
                                    hitung = Val(i.Cells(3).Value.ToString) * Val(i.Cells(2).Value.ToString)
                                    i.Cells(6).Value = hitung
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                        If Not duplikasi Then
                            dt.Rows.Add(.a, .b, .c, "1", .f, "0", hitung)
                            Dim blank As Boolean = True
                            For Each i As DataGridViewRow In tb.Rows
                                If Not i.IsNewRow Then
                                    i.Cells(6).Value = Val(i.Cells(3).Value.ToString) * Val(i.Cells(2).Value.ToString)
                                End If
                            Next
                            For Each _row As DataGridViewRow In tb.Rows
                                blank = True
                                For a As Integer = 0 To _row.Cells.Count - 1
                                    If _row.Cells(a).Value.ToString IsNot Nothing AndAlso _row.Cells(a).Value.ToString <> "" Then
                                        blank = False
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                Next
                                If blank Then
                                    If Not _row.IsNewRow Then
                                        tb.Rows.Remove(_row)
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

sorry for bad english because I am still learning stage